# How to remove Slick slider default slide timing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, slick.js

My Slick slider implementation shows all slides for 1 second after every page reload and I want to remove it. How can I fix this? Below you can see my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="big-box">
  <div class="slick-slides">
    <img src="img/Slider/sliderbild_home_1.jpg">
    <div class="slider-flag">
      <h2>Dinner mit Freunden Geplant?</h2>
      <br />
      <h1><a href="reservation.html">Tisch reservieren</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slick-slides">
    <img src="img/Slider/sliderbild_home_2.jpg">
    <div class="slider-flag">
      <h2>Dinner mit Freunden Geplant?</h2>
      <br />
      <h1><a href="reservation.html">Tisch reservieren</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slick-slides">
    <img src="img/Slider/sliderbild_home_3.jpg">
    <div class="slider-flag">
      <h2>Dinner mit Freunden Geplant?</h2>
      <br />
      <h1><a href="reservation.html">Tisch reservieren</a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.big-box').slick({
    autoplay: true
  });
});
```

CUSTOM CSS:

```
 .slick-slider{
   margin-bottom: 0px;
 }

.slick-slides{
    position: relative;

}
```

Comment: Read the documentation. There would be some options missing, like `auto play:false` or similar..

Comment: This fiddle example should show you what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/qwawfkmj/1/

Comment: @JensB Your code doesn't work, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 3):

This problem occur due to processing time taken by slick slider. It will take some time to create slider till then your images displays as it is.

Comment: Do you know how i can prevent this problem? Or can you give me some advise to use another responsive Jquery Slider?